# About a condition for a continuous mapping to be open.

Tags: general-topology

The text (Foundations of General Topology, by Pervin, Second edition) says

> a (continuous) mapping $f$ of $X$ into $X^*$ is open iff $f(i(E))\subseteq i^*(f(E))$ for every $E\subseteq X$.

EDIT: $i(E)$ is the interior of set $E$ in $X$. Similarly, $i^*$ is the interior operator in $X^*$.

However, shouldn't $f(i(E))=i^*(f(E))$?

Motivation:

1. $i^*(f(E))$ is an open set. Hence $f^{-1}[i^*(f(E))]$ will be an open set in $X$. This open set $\subseteq i(E)$. Hence, $i^*(f(E))\subseteq f(i(E))$
2. $i(E)$ is an open set in $X$. Hence, as $f$ is an open mapping, $f(i(E))$ will be an open set in $X^*$. This open set will be $\subseteq i^*(f(E))$. Hence, $f(i(E))\subseteq i^*(f(E))$
3. From $(1)$ and $(2)$ we conclude that $f(i(E))=i^*(f(E))$.

Comment: What are $i$ and $i^*$? Is $X$ supposed to be a Banach space?

Comment: Also: what book are you using? (Is there ever a reason *not* to specify?)

Comment: @ZevChonoles- Relevant edits made. Sorry again. $X$ can be any topological space, I suppose. No such assumptions have been made in the book yet. It is very elementary stuff.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let $\newcommand{\Int}{\operatorname{Int}}X = \{ 0 , 1 \}$ be given the anti-discrete (trivial) topology, and let $Y = \{ y \}$ be given its only topology.  It is easy to check that the constant mapping $f : x \mapsto y$ is open continuous.  However $$f [ \operatorname{Int} ( \{ 0 \} ) ] = f [ \varnothing ] = \varnothing \subsetneq \{ y \} = \operatorname{Int} ( \{ y \} ) = \operatorname{Int} ( f [ \{ 0 \} ] ).$$

---

As far as your justification goes, while true that $f^{-1} [ \Int ( f [ E ] ) ]$ is open, it may not be a subset of $E$, because $f$ may not be one-to-one.  Therefore the claim that $f^{-1} [ \Int ( f [ E ] ) ] \subseteq \Int (E)$ may be false (and it is in the above example).

Comment: If $E$ maps to $f(E)$, then a subset of $f(E)$ can only be mapped to by a subset of $E$, regardless of whether the mapping is one-to-one, or not. If this is right, then shouldn't $f^{-1}[Int(f[E])]\subseteq Int(E)$?

Comment: @AyushKhaitan: Look at my example, with $E = \{ 0 \}$.  Here $f^{-1} [ \operatorname{Int} ( f [ E ] ) ] = f^{-1} [ \operatorname{Int} ( \{ y \} ) ] = f^{-1} [ \{ y \} ] = \{ 0 , 1 \}  = X$, but $\operatorname{Int} ( E ) = \varnothing$.

Comment: But this wouldn't be a continuous mapping, as the inverse of an open set has to be an open set! What I understand from this is an open set can map to non-open sets in $X^*$, but an open set in $X^*$ can only be mapped to by an open set! Here you've shown that although non-open sets can map to open sets in $X^*$, the _accepted_ inverse of an open set in $X^*$, out of the many possible options of open and non-open sets in $X$, will be an open set. Is my understanding flawed?

Comment: @AyushKhaitan: My space $Y$ (or $X^*$ if you prefer) has only two open sets: $\varnothing$ and $Y$ itself.  Clearly $f^{-1} [ \varnothing ] = \varnothing$ is open in $X$, and $f^{-1} [ Y ] = X$ is also open in $X$.  Thus the mapping is continuous.

Comment: @ArthurFischer- I got that. What I was asking is if $f$ is a continuous mapping, can a set which is NOT open map to an open set? In your example, you've mapped $\{0\}$, which is not open, to $\{y\}$. There might be a gap in my understanding, which I hope to plug. Thanks

Comment: @Ayush: Arthur’s example already answers your question in the affirmative: his $f$ is continuous, and it does map the non-open set $\{0\}$ to the open set $\{y\}$.

Answer (score 3):

Arthur’s minimal example really exposes what’s going on, but you may want to see another example in a more familiar setting.

Let $X=\Bbb R$, let $Y=[0,\to)$ with the subspace topology inherited from $\Bbb R$, and let $$f:X\to Y:x\mapsto x^2\;.$$ Certainly $f$ is continuous. Suppose that $I=(a,b)$ is an open interval in $X$. Then

$$f[I]=\begin{cases}
\left(a^2,b^2\right),&\text{if }0\le a<b\\\\
\left(b^2,a^2\right),&\text{if }a<b\le 0\\\\
\left[0,\max\{a^2,b^2\}\right),&\text{if }a<0<b\;.
\end{cases}$$

so in every case $f[I]$ is open in $Y$, and $f$ is an open map. Let

$$A=\Big(\Bbb Q\cap[0,\to)\Big)\cup\Big((\leftarrow,0)\setminus\Bbb Q\Big)\;,$$

the set of non-negative rationals and negative irrationals. Clearly $A$ is not open in $X$, but $f[A]=Y$ is open in $Y$. Moreover,

$$f[\operatorname{int}A]=f[\varnothing]=\varnothing\subsetneqq Y=\operatorname{int}f[A]\;.$$

Answer (score 0):

I'll attempt to answer my own question. This will be a little theoretical, as compared to Arthur and Brian's brilliant example-illustrated answers.

I stated that ***if set $E\in X$ is mapped to $f(E)$, then a subset of $E$ will be mapped to a subset of $f(E)$.***

This is not necessarily true if this is a many-one mapping. A set $\supset E$ may also be mapped to the same mapping as the subset of $E$. Hence, if $f$ is an open continuous mapping, it is NOT necessary that $f^{-1}[Int(f(E))]\subseteq Int(E)$. The condition I have stated is valid only when $f$ is a one-one or one-many mapping.

As for ***$f(Int(E))\subseteq Int^*(f(E))$***,

1. the relation is $f(Int(E))= Int^*(f(E))$ for one-one and one-many mappings, and
2. the relation is $f(Int(E))\subseteq Int^*(f(E))$ for many-one mapping.